# Data factory- SQL query of historical data with periods of one minute

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to make a copy activity to copy data from an on-premise SQL database with data factory. I need the to modify dynamiccaly the query, so it takes a range of dates, for example ranges of every minute:
So for example: the first copy would be using dynamical content as
...
AND DateTime > '20230131 13:06'
AND DateTime < '20230131 13:07'

and then, the next run would be:
AND DateTime > '20230131 13:07'
AND DateTime < '20230131 13:08'

I tried to use variables like:
AND DateTime > @{variables('starttime')}
AND DateTime < @{variables('endtime')}

It works when I give the times manually to variables but the actual data is for a year, so I need to read the start and end times from a file or somehow automate it. I tried to use "ForEach" block, but the problem is that I can only set one variable as a loop, either start or end time.
what is the best solution for this?
How can I use "ForEach" block on start time and enter the end time in a  way that is one minute after the start time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the start time file, loop through it and add a minute to each time in for loop.

- The following is the output of my look up of csv file containing start_times.

[image]

- Loop through this data. Inside for each I have 2 set variable activities, one for converting start time to a valid format so minute can be added using `addMinutes()` function.

```
@concat(substring(item().start_time,0,4),'-',substring(item().start_time,4,2),'-',substring(item().start_time,6,2),' ',substring(item().start_time,9,5))
```

[image]

- Now, for this format, add minutes and replace the `-` value concatenated above.

```
@replace(addminutes(variables('tp'),1,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'),'-','')
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant.
When I use 
AND DateTime > @{variables('ts')} 
the sql code is like
AND DateTime > 20230131 13:07
which gives error as I need the date surronded by ' sign like: AND DateTime > '20230131 13:07'
tried many time with @concat by different scenarios of using ''' and '''', but it didn't work. CAn you help me on this well ? :)

Comment: You can try opening a new question for this new issue as the issue for this problem is resolved.

Comment: I'm new here, so I'm not allowed to ask a new question in 2 days :)

Comment: Never knew this was a thing. You can just wrap it around single quotes like this `select * from my_table where start_time>'@{pipeline().parameters.start_time}' and end_time<'@{pipeline().parameters.end_time}'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works in Data Factory but in t-sql, you can increase your variables by one minute with the DATEADD function.    [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9gTfTIdM)

```
DATEADD(*interval*, *number of intervals*, *start datetime*)
```

I checked Books Online and it looks like data factory uses datetime_add. It appears to work the same way though.

```
DATETIME_ADD(*interval*, *number of intervals*, *start datetime*)
```

I hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @startdate  datetime = '20230131 13:06'
      , @enddate    datetime
      , @finishdate datetime;
    SET @enddate    = DATEADD(minute, 1, @startdate);
    SET @finishdate = DATEADD(minute, 100, @startdate); --will loop 100 times. 
                                                        --change that to whatever you want.

  WHILE @startdate < @finishdate
    BEGIN
      SELECT data 
        INTO newTable
        FROM oldTable
       WHERE oldTableDate >= @startdate 
         AND oldTableDate <= @enddate;

      SELECT @startdate = DATEADD(minute, 1, @startdate),
             @enddate = DATEADD(minute, 1, @enddate)
     END
```